# Sed on a Makefile

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, makefile

I want to replace my default make target using sed in a shellscript. First I am trying to get sed to work from command line.

My makefile contains:

```
all:
    gcc -Wall -o main main.c
```

I want it to contain:

```
all:
        gcc -Wall -o TEST main.c
```

The sed command I use:

```
sed -i 's/(-o[ ][^ ]+)/-o TEST/g' Makefile
```

It seems to work on https://regexr.com/ but when I run the command in ubuntu it does not edit my Makefile. What could be the reason?

Also is main the default make target, or is main.c the default make target? Some terminology things I don't quite understand yet.

Comment: Please mention your expected output i your POST.

Comment: See the [documentation for `sed` regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html). You need to escape the `+`: `sed -i 's/(-o[ ][^ ]\+)/-o TEST/g' Makefile`. Also, you have superfluous brackets: `sed -i 's/-o [^ ]\+/-o TEST/g' Makefile`

Comment: Are you sure that this is not an [XY-Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? What are you really trying to achieve? Keep in mind that `make` is a text replacement tool in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the BRE (not ERE) POSIX flavor, so the unescaped `(` and `)` in your pattern match literal parentheses and `+` is also parsed as a literal plus symbol. To create a capturing group in a BRE POSIX pattern, you need to use escaped parentheses. Anyways, the parentheses are redundant in the current regex pattern since you are not using placeholders in the replacement pattern. In GNU sed, you may still use `+` in BRE patterns as a *1+ occurrences* quantifier, but you need to escape it.

Use

```
sed -i 's/-o [^ ]\+/-o TEST/g' Makefile
```

Or

```
sed -i 's/-o [^ ][^ ]*/-o TEST/g' Makefile
```

to fix the issue. See the [**online demo**](https://ideone.com/1ExrNo).

Note that `\+` quantifier is not recognized by all `sed` versions, thus, `[^ ][^ ]*` (a non-space followed with 0+ non-spaces) workaround might turn out useful.

Comment: The first line of code you have provided fixes the issue. Thanks! Will this work on Minix 3.3 as well?

Comment: @Athylus If the first solution does not work, `'s/-o [^ ][^ ]*/-o TEST/g'` will work there.

Answer (score 1):

The proper soulution is to parametrize the Makefile.

```
MAIN := main
all:
    gcc -Wall -o $(MAIN) main.c
```

Now you can say `make MAIN=TEST` (or `make MAIN=fnord` or what have you) without modifying anything.

Modifying code is nearly always the wrong solution (whereas *generating* code can be a powerful and versatile technique).